# Timeout not working on perl Net::Telnet

Tags: perl, timeout, telnet

The Timeout is not working on the simple code below:

```
my $t=time;
my $tel = new Net::Telnet (Timeout => 2);
eval{
    $tel->open(Host=>$host,Port=>$port) || print "Not OK";
}
my $interval=time-$t;
print "Seconds: $interval";
```

When I try with some hosts, sometimes I get 20 seconds or more.
I am using ActiveState Perl, Win7.

Answer (score 0):

The telnet protocol involves various automated exchanges, which `Net::Telnet` handles behind the scenes. `open` does more than just connect.

Use this to get a clearer idea of what's going on:

```
my $tel = new Net::Telnet (Timeout => 2, Dump_Log => $filename);
```

Comment: Thanks you. I want to test some proxy servers and I need the fastest way to see if a host:port is responding.